# Sorting and fading out like a killfeed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a CS:GO like killfeed in JavaScript/JQuery.
For everybody who does not know what something like this looks like, I made [this GIF](http://cdn.makeagif.com/media/5-09-2015/7pOCa7.gif).

When you look at my [current JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JumperKenny/t7fp1du0/3/) you can see my current state of work.
I started to try doing it myself in the function `sortList()` in line 42 but the killfeed is not deleting the entrys properly in the right order.
Any tips to fix this?

Comment: there is a much simpler and easier logic for this, hold on ill write an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a much simpler solution.

I think the code is pretty much self explanatory plus added comments in the code, but if you have more questions feel free to ask:

```js
$(function() {
  var feedID = 1;
  //how many feeds to have in the box
  var maxFeedsInBox = 4;
  //feed life span in ms
  var feedLife = 3000;
  var preText = 'Player -> ';
  var randomNames = ['Bot Trevor', 'Bot Troy', 'Bot Dennis', 'Bot Lucy', 'Bot Mark', 'Bot Maxi', 'Bot Kannnix', 'Bot Luis', 'Bot Jan', 'Bot Istso'];
  var linebreaker = "<br />";

  var $image = $('img.clickable');
  var $killfeedbox = $('.killFeedBox');

  //set a timer to run a cleaning function. runs every feedLife ms.
  var $FeedCleaner = setInterval(feedCleaner, feedLife);

  //a function to generate a randon bot name
  function getRandomName() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 0);
    var randomName = randomNames[randomNumber];
    return randomName;
  }

  $image.click(function() {
    //add a feed to the feedbox
    addFeed(preText + getRandomName());
  });

  //a function that adds a feed and colors it with a cycling 4 colors,
  //this function removed the first feed when it passes maximum defined feeds
  function addFeed(txt) {
    var feedsCount = $killfeedbox.children().length;
    console.log(feedsCount);
    if (feedID >= 4) {
      feedID = 0;
    }
    feedID = feedID + 1;
    var $newFeed = $("<span/>").addClass("textfieldCommon").addClass("textfield" + feedID).text(txt);
    if (feedsCount >= maxFeedsInBox) {
      $killfeedbox.children().first().remove();
    }
    $newFeed.appendTo($killfeedbox);
  }

  function feedCleaner() {
    var feedsCount = $killfeedbox.children().length;
    if (feedsCount > 0) {
      $killfeedbox.children().first().remove();
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.textfieldCommon {
  display: block;
}
.textfield1 {
  color: red;
}
.textfield2 {
  color: blue;
}
.textfield3 {
  color: black;
}
.textfield4 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/500x100" class="clickable" />
<br />
<span class="killFeedBox"></span>
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/t7fp1du0/9/)**</kbd>

**UPDATE:**

if you want, here is an animated one: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/t7fp1du0/10/)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow this is exacty what I wanted! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @SamuelBrand you are welcomed :) i added an animated example too.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be interested in such option, but just wanted to point out how easy it is to do such things in some two-way-databinding framework like knockout.js, so instead of writing tons of lines you just operate on the array and the rest is done magically. If you pointed a jquery only for this task it is better to make some small research rather than using jquery just because everybody does.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qybze7ap/)

```
function TableModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.rows = ko.observableArray([]),
    self.addRow = function() {
        self.rows.push( new Date() );
        setTimeout(function(){ self.rows.shift(); }, 3000 + self.rows().length*1000 );
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new TableModel());

<button id="button" data-bind="click: addRow">click</button>
<div id="dash" data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <div data-bind="text:$data"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though this is not exactly what I searched for, it seems to be very interesting and I look forward to learn it some time! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need all the textfield div's, you can just append new entries to the container and set a destroyer on each of them.

```
function KillFeed(container, options) {
    var self = this;
    var names = ['Bot Trevor', 'Bot Troy', 'Bot Dennis', 'Bot Lucy', 'Bot Mark', 'Bot Maxi', 'Bot Kannnix', 'Bot Luis', 'Bot Jan', 'Bot Istso'];
    this.options = $.extend({
        prefix: 'Player ->',
        destroyAfter: 4000,
        max: 4
    }, options);
    this.container = $(container);

    function getRandomArrayItem(arr) {
        return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    }

    function wrapper(name) {
        return $('<div class="feed-instance">' + self.options.prefix + ' ' + name + '</div>');
    }

    function checkMax() {
        var entries = self.container.children();
        if (entries.length >= self.options.max) {
            entries.first().remove();
        }
    }

    this.createEntry = function () {
        var name = getRandomArrayItem(names);
        var entry = wrapper(name);

        checkMax();

        entry.get(0).selfDestroy = setTimeout(function () {
            entry.remove();
        }, self.options.destroyAfter);

        self.container.append(entry);
    };

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jLmq1Lhk/